# shutdown mongodb with auth enabled

Tags: windows, mongodb

I set up mongodb on my local windows machines. I set up the auth as explained in the mongo documentation. I shutdown and restart the server with the auth flag. I switch to the admin db using "use admin" and then use db.auth. It logs me in, but when I try to use the shutdown command (db.shutdownServer) I get told unauthorized. How do I shut down the server (other than closing the cmd prompt)

Comment: What roles does your admin user have?  In order to run the `shutdown` command the [`clusterAdmin` role](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#administrative-roles) is required.

Comment: closing the command prompt will *not* shut down the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the stuff about "use db.auth" in your question, but in general, you are going to need to login to Mongo as a user in the role "clusterAdmin" http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#clusterAdmin.  This works on my system, but I have a LaunchDaemon thingy running which immediately restarts it, but the point is that user "rkuhar" can issue the db.shutdownServer() command from within the mongo shell because his system.user record in the admin database includes the "clusterAdmin" role.

```
bobk-mbp:DM_Server bobk$ mongo -p -u rkuhar localhost:27018/admin
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
Enter password: 
connecting to: localhost:27018/admin
dmReplSet:SECONDARY> db.shutdownServer();
Thu Dec 19 14:48:44.358 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
server should be down...
Thu Dec 19 14:48:44.363 trying reconnect to localhost:27018
Thu Dec 19 14:48:44.365 reconnect localhost:27018 failed couldn't connect to server localhost:27018
>
```

This is what my user "rkuhar" looks like in the admin database.

```
bobk-mbp:DM_Server bobk$ mongo -p -u userAdmin localhost/admin 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
Enter password: 
connecting to: localhost/admin
> db.system.users.find( { user : 'rkuhar' } ).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("526061a45cf44cef5b2ef011"),
    "pwd" : "097df10ea69d71d986fe5e94dbad77b1",
    "roles" : [
        "readWriteAnyDatabase",
        "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
        "clusterAdmin"
    ],
    "user" : "rkuhar"
}
>
```

Comment: I thought clusterAdmin only dealt with shards. Thank you